# Getting Error in iOS 'Heimdall' for target 'arm64-apple-ios'; found: x86_64 "

Tags: ios, swift, macos, xcode12

I was using Heimdall framework in our iOS project.

In Xcode 10, it was working fine earlier, but with the latest Xcode version 12.2 it is showing error : **":0: error: could not find module 'Heimdall' for target 'arm64-apple-ios'; found: x86_64**
"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run `pod deintegrate` and then  `pod install` or `pod update`

Answer (score 1):

There may be better ways to fix this but adding the below to the heimdall/CMakeLists.txt file should work:

```
find_library(CF CoreFoundation)
find_library(IOK IOKit)
target_link_libraries(heimdall ${CF} ${IOK})
```